# Framer motion on NextJS reload animation jumping too fast issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

I am doing an animation for my landing page on NextJS with framer motion, everything works fine on localhost but after I deploy it and tested it out, the animations behavior changed and it's a bit weird. It is animating too fast. I'm using Chrome for local development and production mode testing. I tried using Firefox and the transition works in there fine unlike in Chrome.

**Localhost: (No issue)**
[Localhost](https://i.imgur.com/nIxd4Ep.mp4/)

**Firefox - Deployed: (No issue)**
[Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/3942b8k.mp4/)

**Chrome - Deployed: (Animation issue)**
[Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/JhQHgFI.mp4/)

[Website Link](https://tigershop.vercel.app//)

**My Code**
[Code Repo](https://github.com/AlexisKenAlvarez/tigershopts/blob/main/pages/index.tsx/)

```
<section className="w-full h-auto flex justify-center">
                <div className="w-full max-w-[1400px] md:mx-[8rem] mx-[2rem] h-[85vh] flex flex-col md: md:flex-row">
                    <div className="flex items-center h-full w-full justify-center">
                        <div className="">

                            <motion.h1 initial={{x: -300, opacity: 0}} animate={{x: 0, opacity: 100}} transition={{duration: 0.7}} className="text-greenSteps w-full xl:text-6xl font-[800] uppercase font-raleway md:text-5xl md:w-[20rem] text-center md:text-left text-4xl mt-10 md:mt-0">Welcome<span className="text-heroOrange font-raleway"> Tigers</span></motion.h1>
                            <motion.p  initial={{x: -300, opacity: 0}} animate={{x: 0, opacity: 100}} transition={{duration: 0.7, delay: 0.1}} className="max-w-[23rem] font-poppins text-greenBg mt-8 md:ml-2 ml-0 text-sm lg:text-md md:text-left text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</motion.p>

                            <motion.div initial={{x: -300, opacity: 0}} animate={{x: 0, opacity: 100}} transition={{duration: 0.7, delay: 0.2}}  className={`md:flex md:ml-2 mt-8 rounded-lg hidden items-center justify-center p-[1px] bg-greenButton hover:bg-white w-40 mx-auto`}>
                                <div className="font-inter bg-greenButton text-white p-3 rounded-lg text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-greenHover cursor-pointer select-none w-full">
                                    <p className="tracking-wider">
                                        View products
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </motion.div >

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <motion.div initial={{x: 300, opacity: 0}} animate={{x: 0, opacity: 100}} transition={{duration: 0.7}} className="md:items-center justify-center w-full h-full flex">
                        <div className="xl:w-[33rem] lg:w-[27rem]  md:w-[20rem] w-[15rem] mt-3 md:mt-0">
                            <Image src="/hero/phonetiger.webp" alt="Phone" height="400" width="400" className="w-full h-auto" />

                            <div className="items-center mt-8 justify-center flex md:hidden">
                                <p className="text-center text-greenSteps font-bold">View products</p>
                                <MdOutlineKeyboardArrowDown className="ml-2 text-2xl"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </motion.div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

I tried adding delay on animations before enter but still did not solve, It sometimes works fine on Chrome when the refresh is taking too long, but most of the time the animation behavior is weird and not what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I figured it out by manually adding a setTimeout before calling the component
I also made Hero section a component so I can render it conditionally

```
export const Home: NextPage<Status> = (props) => {
    const { status } = props
    const router = useRouter()
    const [showHero, setHero] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setHero(true)
        }, 700);
    }, [])
    

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(status);
    }, [])
    

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Tigershop</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" key="hero" />
            </Head>
            <Nav status={status}/>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {showHero ? <Hero key="HERO" /> : null}
            </AnimatePresence>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```